# AngularJS: TypeError: undefined is not an object for localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, mocking, karma-jasmine

I want to test the values in `localstorage`. Here is the package I use to store those values: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngstorage

Here is my code:

```
var module = angular.module(‘myModule', ['ngStorage']);                 

 module.controller(‘MyController’, ['$scope', '$localStorage', function($scope,$localStorage){

 $scope.storage = $localStorage;

 $scope.data = {     
   name: “55 Cherry St.“
 };

 $scope.storage.name = $scope.data.name;
 }]);
```

I want to test the above code in `Jasmine and Mocha`. I dont know how I can as it gives me this error now:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'expect($localStorage).to.be') (line 14)
```

Here is my test code:

```
describe('my Module', function () {
  var $controller;
  var $scope;
  var element;

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(module('ngStorage'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    $scope = {};

    inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $compile, $localStorage) {
      var $controller = $controller('myController', {$scope: $scope});
    });
  });

  describe('My controller', function () {

    it('should contain a $localStorage service', inject(function(
      $localStorage
    ) {
      expect($localStorage).not.to.equal(null);
    }));
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine doesn't have a `expect('something').not.to.equal()` function. Use this instead:

```
expect($localStorage).not.toBe(null);
```

Also, while reproducing your error, `myController is not defined`. Fixed using:

```
var $controller = $controller('MyController', {$scope: $scope});  // MyController (uppercase)
```

And I think `beforeEach(module('ngStorage'));` is not necessary, since it already is a dependency of your module.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a variable for it in order to test it.Below is the improvement you need to do in your code

```
describe('my Module', function () {
  var $controller;
  var $scope;
  var element;
  var $localStorage;

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(module('ngStorage'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    $scope = {};

    inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $compile, $localStorage) {
      var $controller = $controller('myController', {$scope: $scope, $localStorage: $localStorage});
    });
  });

  describe('My controller', function () {

    it('should contain a $localStorage service', inject(function(
      $localStorage
    ) {
      expect($localStorage).not.to.equal(null);
    }));
});
});
```

OR

```
expect(controller.$localStorage).not.to.equal(null); //$localStorage is part of controller now
```